# Python: Want to replace itertool with loop

Tags: python, loops

I have got the following piece of code with me:

```
 for (r, c) in itertools.product(range(-1, 2), repeat=2):
        # don't search this square
        if r == 0 and c == 0:
            continue
        if self.row+r < 0 or self.row+r >= board.ROWS:
            continue
        if self.col+c < 0 or self.col+c >= board.COLS:
            continue
        yield ((self.row+r), (self.col+c))
```

All i want to do is to use a loop instead of using itertool to find product.

Comment: Why? What is itertool not doing for you? Also using `itertool` is using a loop, so I don't see what changing it does for you.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)?